# Display Dedicated IP into viewinvoice.tpl and invoicepdf.tpl in WHMCS?

Tags: whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

Hi stack i have one issue that dont know how to resolve. I want to show Dedicated IP from customer order to show like this:

[image]

I make a short check, and found that need to be done into **viewinvoice.tpl** and **invoicepdf.tpl** files. i found that dedicated ip is stores into **tblhosting** table in database.

I found this code:

```
{php}
$clienthosting = $this->get_template_vars(service);
$dbid = $clienthosting['id'];  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT dedicatedip FROM tblhosting WHERE id = $dbid");  
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
$dedicatedip = $result["dedicatedip"];   
$this->assign("dedicatedip", $dedicatedip); 
{/php}
```

and finally to print:

```
           <td>{if $dedicatedip gt 0} - {$dedicatedip}{/if}{/if}</td>
```

and this is code from **invoice.tpl** where is printing data from customer purchase:

```
<tbody>
                            {foreach from=$invoiceitems item=item}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{$item.description}{if $item.taxed eq "true"} *{/if}</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">{$item.amount}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {/foreach}



                            <tr>
                                <td class="total-row text-right"><strong>{$LANG.invoicessubtotal}</strong></td>
                                <td class="total-row text-center">{$subtotal}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {if $taxrate}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="total-row text-right"><strong>{$taxrate}% {$taxname}</strong></td>
                                    <td class="total-row text-center">{$tax}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {/if}
                            {if $taxrate2}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="total-row text-right"><strong>{$taxrate2}% {$taxname2}</strong></td>
                                    <td class="total-row text-center">{$tax2}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {/if}
                            <tr>
                                <td class="total-row text-right"><strong>{$LANG.invoicescredit}</strong></td>
                                <td class="total-row text-center">{$credit}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="total-row text-right"><strong>{$LANG.invoicestotal}</strong></td>
                                <td class="total-row text-center">{$total}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

But this seems that generate white screen only when try to execute. Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

Create php file in `whmcs_dir/includes/hooks/` (say: dedicated_ip.php) and add the following code:

```
<?php
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule as DB;
add_hook('ClientAreaPageViewInvoice', 1, function($vars) { 
    $dedicatedIps = [];

    foreach ($vars['invoiceitems'] as $k => $item) {
        $ip = '';
        if ($item['type'] == 'Hosting') {
            $hosting = DB::table('tblhosting')->select('dedicatedip')->where('id', $item['relid'])->first();
            if (!is_null($hosting)) {
                $ip = $hosting->dedicatedip;
            }
        } 
        $dedicatedIps[$k] = $ip;

    }
    return ['dedicatedIps' => $dedicatedIps];
});
```

This code will run only in the invoice view page, and adds an array of dedicated IPs for each invoice items. Domains for example will have empty ip.

Then in viewinvoice.tpl update the invoice items loop as following:

```
{foreach from=$invoiceitems item=item key=key}
    <tr>
        <td>
        {$item.description}{if $item.taxed eq "true"} *{/if}
        {if $key|in_array:$dedicatedIps}
        <br>IP: {$dedicatedIps[$key]}

        {/if}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">{$item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Hi your asnwer seems to work, but when try to see invoice, dont show dedicated IP for all orders.. See image.. Most of orders have dedicated IP, but not shown in invoice when try to see. https://i.imgur.com/5t0QZXa.png

Comment: I gave you the general idea how to do it, you have the starting point, use error_log(print_r($item, true), 3, __DIR__.'/file.log'); to check if ip is given.

Comment: Where to put that?

Comment: in the hook loop inside if(...)

Comment: SHowing me error when try po put there. https://i.imgur.com/cBQmxrH.png?1  See also table data: For only one order that show me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EZDY.png and table where is visible that almost every order have DedyIP : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZsdJ.png

Comment: Also see this situation.. Its printing Dedicated IP: but there is not any IP adress.. Weird. https://i.imgur.com/YeaU57M.png?1

Comment: you're not php developer?

Comment: error_log(print_r($item, true), 3, DIR.'/file.log'); without use

Comment: change {if $key|in_array:$dedicatedIps} to {if $key|in_array:$dedicatedIps && $dedicatedIps[$key] != ''}

Comment: After inserting your code from before, again is not shown Dedicated IP into invocies.. See https://i.imgur.com/XH8yDZx.png?1 there have IP, but when check invoices, it not shown there. What can be problem?

Comment: in phpmyadmin run SELECT DISTINCT(type) from `tblinvoiceitems` and let me know the output

Comment: After executing this SQL query from phpmyadmin:

`SELECT DISTINCT(type) FROM tblinvoiceitems;`

i got this result: https://i.imgur.com/rEQNp2c.png?1

Comment: ok, change line: if ($item['type'] == 'Hosting') { to if (in_array($item['type'], ['Hosting', 'PromoHosting'])) {

Comment: Updated that line, but looks like still not show everywhere. For example:

Order #27 database data tblhosting: https://i.imgur.com/PMAHvLn.png?1

When check order 27 from whmcs, i dont see Dedicated IP.. See: https://i.imgur.com/FJqc3SU.png?1