# Show dedicated ip into customer invoice WHMCS

Tags: hook, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I searched into Stackoverflow for my work that I want to do, and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162313/display-dedicated-ip-into-viewinvoice-tpl-and-invoicepdf-tpl-in-whmcs/49229853#49229853) helpful, but seems that is not working properly.

What do I?

1. Created a hook into /includes/hooks/ with this code:

   ```
   foreach ($vars['invoiceitems'] as $k => $item) {
   $ip = '';
   if ($item['type'] == 'Hosting') {
       $hosting = DB::table('tblhosting')->select('dedicatedip')- 
   >where('id', $item['relid'])->first();
       if (!is_null($hosting)) {
           $ip = $hosting->dedicatedip;
       }
   } 
   $dedicatedIps[$k] = $ip;

   }
   return ['dedicatedIps' => $dedicatedIps];
   });
   ```
2. Replaced this loop from **viewinvoice.tpl** file with this one:

   ```
   {foreach from=$invoiceitems item=item key=key}
   <tr>
   <td>
   {$item.description}{if $item.taxed eq "true"} *{/if}
   {if $key|in_array:$dedicatedIps}
   <br>IP: {$dedicatedIps[$key]}

   {/if}
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">{$item.amount}</td>
   </tr>
   {/foreach}
   ```

and seems to show Dedicated IP but only for order #4250 in my case. PHPMyAdmin table:

[image from phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EZDY.png)

when check into **tblhosting** table for that order I see Dedicated IP, and it's showing into invoice:

[tblhosting table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZsdJ.png)

but there is Dedicated IP for many other orders too, but when check that Dedicated IP is not shown for that orders. Where is the issue in this code?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49162313/249645

Comment: See `->first()` try removing that.